# Simulation problem for a multivibrator IC in Proteus

Tags: integrated-circuit, simulation, proteus, multivibrator

I have the following circuit in Proteus, and I try to simulate the functionality of the 74HC423 multivibrator IC:
[image]

The problem is whenever I change the values for Rx or Cx, the output's pulse width never changes..
Is it a problem with the simulator?

[image]

Comment: Does it work if you connect pin 14 to ground like it is supposed to be connected?

Comment: I tried, but nothing changed..